# Php - Write variable to file strange behavior

Tags: php, mysql, file, model-view-controller

I'm trying modify a script that i didn't develop. It is used in a commercial website. The goal is to dublicate a template store. Here is just a bit of it.

```
<?php
class ModelToolDuplicate extends Model {
    public function index($store_id,$new_store_name) {
        $stores = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "store` WHERE `store_id` = '".$store_id."'");
        $store = $stores->row;

        $my_file = 'file.txt';
        $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
        $data = 'This is the data';
        fwrite($handle, $data);

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "store SET name = '" . $new_store_name . "', `url` = '" . $store['url'] . "', `ssl` = '" . $store['ssl'] . "'");


        $newstoreid = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "store` ORDER BY store_id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $newstoreid = $newstoreid->row;
```

This code works fine but if after this line :

```
$newstoreid = $newstoreid->row;
```

if i try to add something like :

```
while($rslt = mysql_fetch_array($newstoreid)) {
    fwrite($my_file, $row['store_id'];
}
```

The script stills run but the behavior is... strange. When i use this script to produce a template website, usually it just takes the template website and duplicate it but when i try to deale with variables of the script, it duplicates another website but not the template one. I don't understand cause i just want to print it on a file text...
Do you have any ideas about my problem?

Thanks

Comment: `mysql_` != `mysqli_`

Comment: There's a lot of confusion in this code. Is this a `mysqli` backed application? If so, try and use the object-oriented approach *exclusively*. This avoids mistakes like inadvertently using the obsolete and unrelated `mysql_` interface.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman The script is running and is accessible only via the admin area of the website, though i dont know if its an issue or not.
I just edited the script to the original version sorry for this

Comment: It's always an issue even if you don't realize it. Improper or ineffective escaping is a bug. Just because it's locked behind an admin area doesn't mean it's not exploitable or not a problem. Do it properly the first time and you will never have problems. Do a half-assed job and you'll never know if your code is going to work or blow up later in a huge way.

Comment: All right haha i'm just gonna start from 0! i'm never gonna be able to modify it completly... thank you @tadman

Comment: Don't stress about it too much. Using the `bind_param` method means your data *will* be escaped properly and you won't fall victim to a SQL injection attack. It's a very good habit to get into, it makes your queries easier to read, and you can often clean up a lot of mess by organizing things around this principle. As a note, PDO makes it even easier by using named placeholders, though that may not be an option if you're already committed to `mysqli`.

Comment: It's also possible that your `Model` class, which is presumably part of some ORM, has methods for doing this you just haven't used yet. Look at the documentation to see if there's a way for doing what you want instead of going at it the brute-force way.